# Is this the way to communicate between controller of directives and factory?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-factory

I am re-writing an entire code for a hotel-client into angular.
Kinda newbie in angular.
**Questions**
***1.***  I wanted to know, if this is the way to write a `directive` for a menu utilizing a `factory` or is there a better way?
***2.*** Is this the way to expose `menuItems` from `directive` to `template`?

**index.html**

```
<menu></menu>
```

**main.js**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.factory('menuItems',function(){
    var items = [{'name':'kabab'},
                 {'name':'chicken'},
                 {'name':'egg'},
                 {'name':'noodles'}]
    return items
})
.directive('menu',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template:"<ul><li ng-repeat='item in menuItems'>"+
                  '{{item.name}}' +
                   "</li></ul>",
        scope:{},
        bindToController:true,
        controllerAs:'menuCtrl',
        controller:function($scope,menuItems){
            $scope.menuItems = menuItems;
        }
})
```

Comment: Yes, and it's a start. If you plan to use the factory to call an API later, then this is the way to go for now. However, I would change always return method helpers from a factory, and then call it in the directive to set it to the scope. Its hard for me to give you further advice unless I know the bigger image.

Comment: Use either `controller` or `link` properties, not both

Comment: @Strawberry:will post a new question rewriting the code including method helpers and also will add some extra features, so that you will have something to look at..... Hoping my start i posted here his correct

Comment: @lyjackal Why can't you use both? You can definitely use both, but they serve different purposes.

Comment: @lyjackal:why not? are you telling, never to use a `controller` and `link` together, or are you telling it only for this example  ??

Comment: From directive tutorial " Best Practice: use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link." I guess you can use both, but I don't really see the point in this example

Comment: if you would have mentioned **in this example**  in your 1st comment, it would have avoided confusion

Comment: @Strawberry:Is this the way to expose `menuItems` to the template ?